# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left[x^2\right]}{\sin x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Test whether the following limit exists or not :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left[x^2\right]}{\sin x^2}$$

Here , $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\left[x^2\right]}{\sin x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{0}{\sin x^2}=0$. And $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left[x^2\right]}{\sin x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{0}{\sin x^2}=0$. So limit exists and its value is $0$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Yup that's right.

Comment: The proof is correct because for $-1< x<1$ we have $[x^2]=0$, at least assuming that $[a]$ means the greatest integer $\le a$.  (That is also written $\lfloor a\rfloor$.)

Comment: As x approaches 0 from the negative direction isn't [x]=-1?

Comment: but what about the $\frac{0}{0}$ form? what do you do about $\sin(x^2)$

Comment: @ The Oddbod Number) What is the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x}$ ?

Comment: @panja717  what does square braccet represents?

Comment: Why do you say that @DeNiSkA ? Looks like a correct proof to me. Assuming that $[x]$ has the IMO default meaning: $[x]=n$ for all $x\in [n,n+1)$ for all reals $x$ and all integers $n$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen he is taking individual limit for both numerator and denominator and we know that for $\frac{1}{\sin x^2}$ limit doesn't exist so product of limit rule can't be applied here

Comment: it is same as  $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sin x}{x}$

as you know limit of sin x at 0 is 0 so we will get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x}=0$ which is weird!!

Comment: No, he isn't doing it like that. Look at it again, @DeNiSkA . The numerator is constant zero, when $-1<x<1$.

Comment: oh!! ya ya .. i got bit confused but now it's ok!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot forget about the ${\sin x^2}$ in the denominator as this causes the fraction within the limit to evaluate to $\frac{0}{0}$, which is an indeterminate form. i.e. You cannot divide by $0$.

What we want to employ here is **L'Hospital's Rule** which, in layman's terms, allows us to take the derivative of both the numerator and denominator separately. We apply this rule anytime our fraction within a limit evaluates to a **indeterminate form**. Ex: $\frac{0}{0}$, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ , ...

In our case we can simplify the limit from:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin x^2}$$
To:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x}{2x\cos x^2}$$
The $2x$ in the numerator and denominator cancel to simplify the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos x^2}$$
Which evaluates to:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos (0)^2} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$
Therefore:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin x^2} = 1$$

Comment: The function in the question is $[x^2]/\sin x^2$. $[x^2]=0$, when $|x|<1$, right?